Applying a differential operator twice
Given
$$u(x,y) = \sin^{-1}{\sqrt{\frac{x^\frac{1}{3} + y^\frac{1}{3}}{x^\frac{1}{2} + y^\frac{1}{2}}}}$$
I was asked to show
$$\big({x\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x}}+y\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{y}}}\big)^2 u = \frac{\tan u}{12}\big(\frac{13}{12}+\frac{\tan^2u}{12}\big)$$
First of all let us denote the operator $\big({x\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x}}+y\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{y}}}\big)$ as $D$
Now let $v(x,y) = \sin(u)$
Clearly $v(x,y)$ is a homogenous equation of degree $\frac{-1}{12}$, hence applying Euler's theorem and chain rule on $v$ we get
$$D(u) = -\frac{\tan u}{12}$$
Now let's apply this operator on both sides again and simplifying using chain rule we get
$$D^2 (u) = \frac{\tan u}{12}\big(\frac{1}{12}+\frac{\tan^2u}{12}\big)$$ which is lacking a $\frac{\tan u}{12}$ from the RHS.
This is where my assumption kicks in. Here I assumed that $D(D(u))$ is equal to $D^2(u)$. However it turns out that is not the case. In fact on calculation I found out
that $$D(D(u)) = D^2(u) + D(u)$$
I want to know what exactly breaks in this case and why can't we write $D(D(u))$ equal to $D^2(u)$ and if there is some way of finding $D(D(u))$ faster instead of applying the operator again and again and then seeing what it translates to?
PS: Here is what I am referring to from Euler's theorem Generalised euler theorem
Edit: Here I am referring $$ D^2 = {x^2\frac{\partial{}^2}{\partial{x}^2}+2xy\frac{\partial{}^2}{\partial{x}\partial{y}}+y^2\frac{\partial{}^2}{\partial{y}^2}}$$
(This is assuming that partial derivatives are continuous and hence the order doesn't matter)
and
$$D \circ D = {x\frac{\partial{D}}{\partial{x}}+y\frac{\partial{D}}{\partial{y}}}$$
which on simplification turns out to be
$$D \circ D = D^2 + D$$

Could you edit your question and write out how operators $D^2$ and $D \circ D$ look like? You can use some dummy function $f$ and use both operators on it to see what happens

In particular, the standard definition of $D^2$ is $$ D^2u = D(Du). $$

In my view, the expression the OP calls $D^2$ is not a square of $D$ in any meaningful sense.
Yes, we can use a FOIL-like operation to begin expanding
\begin{align*}
D\circ D &= \biggl( x\frac\partial{\partial x} + y\frac\partial{\partial y} \biggr) \biggl( x\frac\partial{\partial x} + y\frac\partial{\partial y} \biggr) \\
&= x\frac\partial{\partial x} \biggl( x\frac\partial{\partial x} \biggr) + x\frac\partial{\partial x} \biggl( y\frac\partial{\partial y} \biggr) + y\frac\partial{\partial y} \biggl( x\frac\partial{\partial x} \biggr) + y\frac\partial{\partial y} \biggl( y\frac\partial{\partial y} \biggr).
\end{align*}
However, it is not true that $x\frac\partial{\partial x} \bigl( x\frac\partial{\partial x} \bigr) = x^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$. Indeed, for any smooth function $f$,
$$
x\frac\partial{\partial x} \biggl( x\frac\partial{\partial x} \biggr) f = x\frac\partial{\partial x} \biggl( x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \biggr) = x\biggl( \frac\partial{\partial x} x \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + x\frac\partial{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \biggr) = x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + x^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}.
$$
And similarly for $y\frac\partial{\partial y} \bigl( y\frac\partial{\partial y} \bigr)$.
If we want to isolate the mistake to a specific step, it would be an implicit step near the sentence “This is assuming that partial derivatives are continuous and hence the order doesn't matter”. It's true that (for nice functions) it doesn't matter what order we apply partial derivatives; but it certainly matters what order we apply partial derivatives mixed with multiplication by functions; that's why $x\frac\partial{\partial x} \bigl( x\frac\partial{\partial x} \bigr)$ is not the same as $x^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$.
